# .NET 6 IHubContext Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm working on a simple .NET 6 application to enable data update notifications in our front-end application.  I've built something similar in .NET 5 before, but I'm running across a DI issue that's got me stumped.  In 5, all hubs that were mapped automatically have an IHubContext that is set up in the container for them as well.  That doesn't appear to be the case anymore in 6.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext`1[SignalRNotifications.Hubs.NotificationHub]' while attempting to activate 'SignalRNotifications.Controllers.NotificationController'.

The new non-startup DI in 6 looks weird to me, but I'm just not seeing anything available that says how to fix it.  Any suggestions on how to get an IHubContext to inject into my controller?

Thanks!

Update: Here is some pertinent code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using SignalRNotifications.Hubs;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/NotificationHub");
});

app.Run();
```

Dependency injection is done in the controller in the most predictable of ways:

```cs
namespace SignalRNotifications.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NotificationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _notificationContext;

        public NotificationController(IHubContext<NotificationHub> notificationContext)
        {
            _notificationContext = notificationContext;
        }
```

Comment: @mason Updated.  The code looks exactly like similar code that works in .NET 5.

Comment: @mason Thanks for fixing the formatting on the code block.  I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.

Comment: Your code looks a lot better. You might feel it wasn't important to show this, but many times people think there's nothing wrong with their code and just expect us to take them at their word. Once we finally convince them to show us, we often spot issues with it. I've not worked with SignalR Core, but based on looking at the documentation, what you have here looks correct. However I would probably remove everything from the code sample I share that isn't related to the issue, following the guidelines of [mcve]. For example, we don't need to know about your Swagger or CORS configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext`1[SignalRNotifications.Hubs.NotificationHub]'
> while attempting to activate
> 'SignalRNotifications.Controllers.NotificationController'.

The issue might be related to you having installed the wrong version of SignalR and adding the wrong namespace reference. You are using `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext`, instead of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubContext`.

According to your code and refer to the [Asp.net Core SignalR document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0#get-an-instance-of-ihubcontext), I create a sample and [inject an instance of IHubContext in a controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0#get-an-instance-of-ihubcontext), everything works well. But I notice that when using the `IHubContext`, we need to add the `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;` namespace, like this:

[image]

So, please check your code and try to use:

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
```

Comment: Outstanding work, @Zhi Lv.  You were right, the injection was working, but I was grabbing the IHubContext<T> from the wrong namespace.